# Get multivalues in a associative array containing other array

Tags: php, mysql

In the following example I need to get contacts as an array.

What's the right way to do it.

```
    $query = "SELECT cl.name, ct.phone, ct.address
              FROM clients cl
              LEFT JOIN contacts ct ON cl.id = ct.id";

    $statement = $conexion->query($query);

    while($row = $statement->fetch_assoc()) {
        $data[] = array(
            'name'= $row['name'],
            'contacts' = array( 
                 'phone'= $row['phone'],
                 'address'= $row['address']
            )
        )
    };

    echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: You need `=>` in the array not `=`.

Comment: Use an ide that will display syntax errors & auto format your code for you.

Comment: You are also missing a semi colon, and if you used an ide, it would highlight where. good luck.

Comment: Thanks AbraCadaver and Andrew. It was '=>' and semi colon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while($row = $statement->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $data[] = array(
            'name'=> $row['name'],
            'contacts' => array(
                'phone'=> $row['phone'],
                'address'=> $row['address']
            )
        );
    }
```